# On Javascript scope resolution

Tags: javascript, scope, this

On the console, when you enter

`blahblah` and hit enter, you expectedly get the `Unrecognized ReferenceError`.

but...

When you enter `this.blahblah` instead, you get `undefined` ( meaning no errors )

Why is that?

When did `blahblah` find a space for itself in the memory to have that special value (`undefined`) assigned to it?  - It looks like, when I do `this.blahblah`, it has the effect of executing`var blahblah;` on the fly.

Any comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of `this.blahblah` you are referring to the *property* of the `this` object (the `window` in your case).

In JavaScript, when you try to get a non existing property of an object it will return an `undefined` type.

In the first case however, calling simply `blahblah`, you are trying to call an object with the reference called `blahblah`. If that does not exist, JavaScript will throw a `ReferenceError` instead.

JavaScript has many ways of telling you something is not there.

Comment: Technically it doesn't throw an error. The value of `this.blahblah` is just `undefined`.

Comment: @DavidBarker You are totally correct, my wording was a bit too dramatic, adjusted it.

Comment: Accessing `blahblah` is not "calling" any object

Comment: @6502 I know that is not entirely the correct verbiage. My point was to tell apart the two situations illustrated without becoming too overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same when you write to console

```
obj
Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined(…)
```

and

```
var obj = {a: 1}
obj.b
undefined
```

with `this` - you are refering to global object

Answer (score 0):

The first one is *undeclared*, the second one *undefined*. Since `this` refers to the window in the browser, the interpreter tries to find a property `blahblah` of it and fails, so returns `undefined`.

You can verify that no variables are automatically created by trying to find the property of an undefined variable, such as `bluh.blahblah`. You'll get an *undeclared* error again because `bluh` won't be found in any scope.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a member of an object that doesn't exist simply returns `undefined` on reading because the language was "designed" that way.

If instead you assign a value to it then you're creating the member.

When using an identifier that is not a local the language accesses the global `window` object, but first checks if the member actually exists and gives an error otherwise. This is weird but just accept it... it's this way because it's this way. There's no solid logic reason.

If you think this is questionable then be prepared for much much worse. Logic is not a really important part of the Javascript language. You should remember that Javascript wasn't indeed given any serious thought at design time (basically it was created overnight) and, as a language, is close to hideous.

The internet big bang however solidified it in its current sad state and it's not something that will be "fixed" in incompatible ways as changing it would simply break the whole world wide web. Normally "standards" are defined after a lot of thinking and experimentation but this didn't happen for Javascript and what was standardized it's that overnight hack.

Just enjoy the really fantastic runtime environment (HTML5 browsers, node js) and pay a lot of attention when writing your code.

PS: Don't even use or look the specs about what `==` does in Javascript. It's just nonsense.

Comment: I disagree with you on what you think of javascript in general but, I like your first sentence - which explains the situation. `Accessing a member of an object that doesn't exist simply returns undefined on reading because the language was "designed" that way.`

Comment: @AverageJoe: Not sure what you don't agree with. That's almost an overnight hack is history, not an opinion you can agree or disagree with. If you think that it's a logical language then be prepared for a lot of debugging... (e.g. `[1]==1`, `1=="1 "` but `[1]!="1 "`... i.e. equality is not transitive... and this without using any "strange" value like `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`).

Comment: the problem is the using of the `==` as opposed to using `===`. If we ,for comparison purposes, were to stick to using `===` (or the `!==` for that matter )  ALL THE TIME ,  then the results would be much less surprising. It would be predictable to say the least. Most of us use == instead of === though. That's a big mistake. I understand your frustration but no language is perfect anyway and certainly JS is no exception. But it does support functions being first class citizens and as well as closures..  And the node.js is no joke. That's my opinion.

Comment: @AverageJoe: there are quite a few points very questionable in Javascript... `==` is the most evident (i.e. the "default" comparison operator is basically unusable and modern IDEs even warn you on every single use as a potential mistake). Another pearl is `with` that is totally broken by "design". Javascript is however powerful and the runtime environments and the implementations are amazing (thanks to the billions of dollars that were thrown at it). As a formal language however it sucks big time for many many reasons. Today is one of my preferred tools.